# How do I define component type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, higher-order-components

I'm trying to write a function that takes `Higher Order Components` as a argument and returns component connected with the redux store. But this code have a type error in the last line. How to I define type correctly?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'
import { AppState } from '~/store'
import { decrement, increment } from '~/store/home'

export type CountableProps = StateType & DispatchType

type StateType = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  count: state.home.count
})

type DispatchType = ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
  decrement: () => dispatch(decrement())
})

const createCountableComponent =
  <P extends CountableProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
    class extends React.Component<P> {
      componentDidMount() {
        // do something...
      }

      render() {
        return <Component {...this.props} />
      }
    }

export const countable = <P extends CountableProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(createCountableComponent(Component))
```

Type error

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof ConfigurableComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<CountableProps, P>>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly typing the connect function seems to work:

```
export const countable = <P extends CountableProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
    connect<StateType, DispatchType, Omit<P, keyof (StateType & DispatchType)>>(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(createCountableComponent(Component) as any);
```

We can cast createCountableComponent(Component) as any, since we typed connect with correct typings (state, dispatch and ownProps types). This means when you use this component you will only see props that are not Countable (wich is the desired solution).

So:

```
class Test extends React.Component<{test: string}> {
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
};

countable(Test)
```

will give an error, while:

```
class Test extends React.Component<CountableProps & {test: string}> {
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
};

const Test2 = countable(Test)
<Test2 /> -> intelisense will only give you test now :)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried, but got another type error.
`TS2345: Argument of type 'ComponentType<P>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<CountableProps>'.`